# Phone ignoring htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am serving videos depending on the phone's user agent with an htaccess file.  So far it works on smartphones but not in some non-smartphones like Motorola Razor V3. Is there a way to do the same thing with php so I can have the htaccess and php file for backup? This is my htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond <is smartphone>
RewriteRule videos/(.*) mysite.com/videos/high/$1
RewriteCond <is non-smartphone>
RewriteRule videos/(.*) mysite.com/videos/low/$1
```

Comment: Good luck with this.  There are whole libraries and databases dedicated to mobile device detection.  You are probably not going to be able to do this with a high degree of accuracy in an .htaccess rule.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of them, but this way was much easier and simpler.  I see still needs some tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

Could you redirect based on $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']?

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == 'xyz') {
        header("Location: mysite.com/videos/high".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);     
    }
    elseif $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == 'abc') {
        header("Location: mysite.com/videos/low".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);             
    }

    exit;
?>
```

You might need to use an array to determine which user agents are for smartphones (Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile).

Comment: I tried your code but I get 404 no found.  $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) is not getting anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for a full php implementation is to use the `mobile_detect` class. It's pretty thorough and catches most devices I've seen so far. It even supports tablets.

https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

Comment: HI. Yes, I know that one, I've been trying to get this to work for a while now and I saw different versions on github but they work better for smartphone and my videos are targeted to non-smartphones.